# Updating single user data mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I want to make an button in c# and if admin clicks it user gets banned something like ban button but i don't know how to make it below is my code

`MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter("update licenses where username = '" + usernbox.Text + "' set banned = 'true'", conn);`

Comment: your update statement is backwards, it is `UPDATE table_name SET column_name = value WHERE conditions`... But, your coding is **not secure**, you should check what parametrized queries are and why you should use them.

Comment: please use ***parameterised queries*** - building SQL queries by concatenation etc. is a recipe for disaster. not only is it a source for many hard to debug syntax errors, it's also a wide, open gate for ***[SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/)***.

Comment: like this?

MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter("UPDATE licenses SET banned = true WHERE username = '" + usernbox.Text + "'", conn);

Comment: @niqu1337 not like this, because it is insecure

Comment: @nbk i know so send me working and secure

Comment: @Cleptus can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Update command lopks like this

```
string query = "UPDATE licenses SET banned = 'true'" + 
               "WHERE username = @username";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, serverconnection);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", usernbox.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

if course you should check if `serverconnection` is open prior to the command and use the name of your mysql connction